# How can i use'!' in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

consider this code:

```
 <li class="active" hidden="@ViewBag.isAdmin">
```

How can i write `!ViewBag.isAdmin` in razor?
please not to !.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this:

```
@(!ViewBag.isAdmin)
```

[image]

Please see   [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx):

Comment: Where in that screenshot is the syntax you showed explained? :)

Comment: @CodeCaster i dont want show  the syntax i want just insert complete link.

Answer (score 11):

Use some parentheses:

```
@(!ViewBag.isAdmin)
```

[Phil Haack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598/haacked) wrote a [great summary of Razor syntax](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

you should infact completely define what you intend to render as string

```
<li class="active" hidden="@Html.Raw(ViewBag.isAdmin?"true":"false")">
```

Comment: Even better, globalise 'true' and 'false' into resx files.

Comment: @Gusdor Could you explain that?